# Call a GraphQL Mutation once after React component mounts

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

After a user creates a profile, they receive a link in their email that sends them back to the site with a `verifyToken` in the url. If the token matches the token that is stores in the database, their `isVerified` status is stored in the database with the value `true`.

**new-profile.js**

```js
import VerifyEMail from '../components/VerifyEmail';

const NewProfilePage = props => (
  <div>
    <VerifyEMail verifyToken={props.query.verifyToken} />
  </div>
);

export default NewProfilePage;
```

Currently, I have this implemented and working using a form with a "Verify" button that the user must click to call the graphQL mutation, `verifyEmail`. Since this sets the `isVerified` value to `true` in the database, I know that everything is working as it should.

**../components/VerifyEmail.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const VERIFY_EMAIL_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation VERIFY_EMAIL_MUTATION($verifyToken: String!) {
    verifyEmail(verifyToken: $verifyToken) {
      isVerified
    }
  }
`;

class VerifyEmail extends Component {
  render() {
    const { verifyToken } = this.props;
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={VERIFY_EMAIL_MUTATION} variables={{ verifyToken }}>
        {verifyEmail => (
          <form
            onSubmit={async () => {
              await verifyEmail(verifyToken);
            }}
          >
            <button type="submit">Verify</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}

VerifyEmail.propTypes = {
  verifyToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default VerifyEmail;
```

However, I really don't want to force my users to have to click a button to fire the mutation. I would like it to be called once the component loads. I have been racking my brain for a day and a half on this, tried so many things, and just can't seem to find anything that works.

I've seen some solutions using [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), [Apollo hooks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/), componentDidMount, etc. My mind is just having a difficult time seeing it any more. This link had some of the best solutions that I found so far, but I couldn't figure out how to implement them...
[[Feature idea] Execute a mutation on mount #1939](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1939)

Any help to point me in the right direction would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far simpler application when using React hooks:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function VerifyEmail({ verifyToken }) {
  const [ verifyEmail, { loading, data, error }] = useMutation(VERIFY_EMAIL_MUTATION);
  useEffect(() => {
    verifyEmail({
      variables: { verifyToken },
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {data && <p>Verified successfully!</p>}
      {error && <p>Error!</p>}
    </>
  )
}
```

If you somehow want to keep using classes, the only solution is to create a component and utilise `componentDidMount` of the component for this purpose.

```
// Current component:
<Mutation mutation={VERIFY_EMAIL_MUTATION} variables={{ verifyToken }}>
  {verifyEmail => (
    <SendEmail token={verifyToken} verify={verifyEmail} />
  )}
</Mutation>

// Send Email component
class SendEmail extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { token, verify } = this.props;
    verify(token);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //handle loading, data and error states
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I had tried using the useEffect() hook a few times in a functional component, but now I see I was using it wrong. I think I need to study up on React Hooks a bit more.

One thing you may want to add to your answer in case this helps others is to import  { useMutation } from 'react-apollo'. That was another route I had taken but wasn't quite sure how to implement it. I think in the end, I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks again.